# findViewById(2131230729) o que são esses números?

Tags: java, android

Estou analisando uma classe de um projeto app do Android, sou novo e não entendi esses números dentro do `findViewById(2131230729)`, dentro do parenteses era para ter R.id."layout" como faço através desse número para descobrir o Layout?

Comment: É o ID de uma elemento. Toda relação fica na classe `R.java`.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você faz referência com o `findViewById()`, e colocar `R.id.input`, esse *id* é um inteiro, todos os *ids* de sua aplicação pegam a referência do *id* por um inteiro. Essa referência vem do `R.java`, lá é onde fica salvo esses *ids*. Ex:

```
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/input"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:inputType="text"/>
```

O id `@+id/input` vai para o `R.java` como um inteiro, ele é transformado assim para referência futura do `findViewById`, por exemplo.